# Bash output in function not as expected

Tags: bash

I have the following simple example of which I don't understand how it comes to the output:

```
#!/bin/bash

function wtf() {
    echo -e "test1" >&1
    sleep 2
    echo -e "test2" >&1
}

a=$(wtf)
echo $a
```

The output on the terminal is AFTER 2 seconds `test1 test2`

When I change the last two lines just to `wtf` then the output is

```
 test1
 test2 #after 2 seconds
```

1. Why is in the first version the `test1 test2` in the same line?
2. Why does the output of the line `test1 test2` need 2 seconds to show up since only the second `test2` should show up after 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(...)` captures the `stdout` of the commands inside the subshell.
The `echo -e` statements are not printed to the `stdout` of the calling shell,
but get buffered in the subshell.
If you remove the `echo $a` command then nothing will be printed at all.

The subshell in this example doesn't exit until `wtf` completes.
That's why you have to wait 2 seconds, so that the calling shell gets back control, and does `echo $a`, printing all the output that was captured by the subshell.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, is there a way to print to the stdout anyways in the function?

Comment: `stdout` will be captured by the subshell, so no, you cannot. You could print to `stderr` though, with `echo test3 >&2`